# How do I specify user properties with Thymeleaf?

Tags: html, thymeleaf

```
<div class="video" data-id="video_1119353_1_vod"
data-src="videos/c57c804c-33a9-4b37-8125-b92bfd16ba9b.mp4"
data-type="video" data-auto="true"
data-m-src="videos/1a4c6f3b-eb4b-4f81-be4a-6788c5c89544.mp4"
data-omni="kv_2:런칭 _play video"
data-coverImg-src="images/346233/55735214-fd99-4fdc-964f-5582e30278e03133.jpg?$ORIGIN_JPG$"
data-coverImgM-src="images/346233/4775d205-3af4-418d-848e-021fe856cf823133.jpg?$ORIGIN_JPG$">
</div>
```

How can I write with thymeleaf  in a situation like this?